# Repeatedly remove characters from string

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, repeat

```
>>> split=['((((a','b','+b']
>>> [ (w[1:] if w.startswith((' ','!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', "(", ")", '-', '_', '+', '=', '~', ':', "'", ';', ',', '.', '?', '|', '\\', '/', '<', '>', '{', '}', '[', ']', '"')) else w) for w in split]
['(((a','b','b']
```

I wanted `['a', 'b', 'b']` instead.

I want to create a repeat function to repeat the command. I make my split clear all the `'('` from the start. Suppose my split is longer, I want to clear all `(((` in front of the words. I don't use `replace` because it will change the `'('` in between of words.

E.g. if the `'('` is in the middle of a word like `'aa(aa'`, I don't want to change this.

Comment: People, the OP tried something, demonstrated that, and managed to explain what they are doing and why. I don't see any reason to downvote this question, really.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I think the edit helped based on what it looked like before

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: all I did was format the code and clean up the language a bit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I did not dv, I am just saying it was unreadable before you edited

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to repeat your expression, you are not using the right tools, is all. You are looking for the [`str.lstrip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
[w.lstrip(' !@#$%^&*()-_+=~:\';,.?|\\/<>{}[]"') for w in split]
```

The method treats the string argument as a *set* of characters and does exactly what you tried to do in your code; repeatedly remove the left-most character if it is part of that set.

There is a corresponding [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) for removing characters from the end, and [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove them from both ends.

Demo:

```
>>> split=['((((a', 'b', '+b']
>>> [w.lstrip(' !@#$%^&*()-_+=~:\';,.?|\\/<>{}[]"') for w in split]
['a', 'b', 'b']
```

If you really needed to repeat an expression, you could just create a new function for that task:

```
def strip_left(w):
    while w.startswith((' ','!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', "(", ")", '-', '_', '+', '=', '~', ':', "'", ';', ',', '.', '?', '|', '\\', '/', '<', '>', '{', '}', '[', ']', '"')):
        w = w[1:]
    return w

[strip_left(w) for w in split]
```

Comment: your comment is great